# Bootstrap Alerts Not coming back after auto close

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have an angularjs app which I am using bootstrap alerts in my modals. I have more than 1 alert which can come up. I made my alerts to auto disappear after a few seconds but if the user gets another alert, it doesn't show. It only shows once and that is it, I have to reload the page for it to show up again.

The alert is being controlled through the controller through API connection. for example: If the user doesn't have the amount for purchase, then the alert shows up.

**Here is the controller.js:**

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
                $(".alert").fadeTo(1000, 0).slideUp(1000, function(){
                    $('#alert').hide(); 
                });
            }, 1500);
```

**Here is my HTML:**

```
<div ng-show="gold_error" role="alert" class="alert alert-danger">{{gold_error}}</div>
```

Comment: Do not use jquery with angular js.

Comment: you can do this using angular ui https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: Thanks. But it closes them, if I close them then I cant call upon it again